# GridView Remove one definition

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to create a web page with the aps.net framework and I connect to the SQL server successfully and I want to display the data from the database in the Grid View and there are a search box and dropdown list but there is an error when I try to search
this is the error message:

**Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'GridView1'.  Remove one definition.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'GridView1'.  Remove one definition.**

and my code viewpage1.aspx
**the GridView**

```
 &nbsp;<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" Format="dd/MM/yyyy" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="InvoiceID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3">
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
```

-and this the **sqldatasource**

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:connStr %>" SelectCommand="Select * from [Portal].[fn_GetInvoices] (@SearchText) where CompanyCode=@CompanyCode and InvoiceDate between @fromDate and @toDate">
        <SelectParameters>
```

viewpage1.aspx.cs

```
sqlcomm.CommandText = sqlquery;
            sqlcomm.Connection =  sqlconn;   
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcomm);
            adapter.Fill(dt);
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Try removing the `DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3"` from your GridView controller. You are filling your GridView with the DataTable.

Comment: I try to remove it but when I try to search no data is displayed.

Comment: Yes i don't know if you are "refreshing" in any way your GridView. Not enough code is displayed. Try the other way. Comment `GridView1.DataSource = dt; GridView1.DataBind();` and check. The exception is pretty much self explanatory. Your are definig 2 Data sources for your Gridview. If you remove one it's going to work.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common error message.

I OFTEN use the wizards to build a gridview I use this:

[image]

From above, I choose create new data source.

I let the wizard run.

BUT THEN we wind up with some MESSAY sqldatasource in the web page. I do NOT like them, and they NEAR ALWAYS just cause you pain.

So, what I will then do this:

Remove the sqldata source from the web markup - you don't' need that mess anyway.

eg this:

```
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CSharpWebApp.Properties.Settings.TEST4 %>" 
                SelectCommand="SELECT [ID], [Fighter], [Engine], [Thrust], [Description], [ImagePath] 
                FROM [Fighters]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

DELETE the above!!!!

Now WHEN you WILL use code to load up the Gridview? Then you ALSO must turn off (remove) the fact that you NOT GOING to use the sql data source anymore.

So in your GV, remove this:

[image]

So, all that error message is telling you is you are trying to set the data source in "code" but you ALREADY have a sql datasource setup in the markup.

So, get in the habit of blowing out and removing the sqldata source on the page, and ALSO remove the GV data source setting in the markup.

So, now say I will have this GV, and NOT have ANY data source in the markup in the web page. (and I recommend you do this). So, I still VERY often use the wizards. Even for a dropdown list, a gridview, repeaters, and even listview (my favorite).

So, run wizards - build the markup

Then blow out (remove) the SqlDataSource, and the
DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" from the control (in this case gv).

So, as noted, you cannot have BOTH a DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" and THEN try to use code. It is one or the other - and that's what the error message is telling you.

So, now we have this markup:

(and the wizards generated most of this for me!!!)

```
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table"  >
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Fighter" HeaderText="Fighter"  />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Engine" HeaderText="Engine"  />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Thrust" HeaderText="Thrust"  />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="btnImage" runat="server" Height="68px" Width="149px"
                            OnClientClick ="popimage(this);return false"
                            ImageUrl = '<%# Eval("ImagePath") %>' /> 
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

Just nice clean markup - no Sqldatasource junk.

Now we are free to write normal code like a normal human, and we can fill the grid like this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadGrid();
    }

    void LoadGrid()
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from Fighters", conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
                GridView1.DataSource = rstData;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
```

And our results are now this:

[image]

Ok, so now lets add a search box above the GV to search the GV.

Say you can type in the first few chars of the Fighter jet name, and we want to filter by that:

So, drop in a text box above the GV, + search button.

We now have say this:

```
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Search for Fighter jet" Font-Size="Large"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" Style="margin-left:15px" Font-Size="Large"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="cmdSearch" runat="server" Text="search"
            style="margin-left:15px" CssClass="btn"
            />
        <br />
        <br />

            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table"  >
                <Columns>
```

So, now the page with searching looks like this:

Say we search for Lockheed - but even just typing in Lock would be fine.

thus:

[image]

And now our code can say be this:

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadGrid("");
    }

    void LoadGrid(string MySearch)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from Fighters ", conn))
            {
                if (MySearch != "")
                {
                    cmdSQL.CommandText += @" WHERE Fighter LIKE @Fighter + '%'";
                    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("Fighter", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = MySearch;
                }
                conn.Open();
                DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
                GridView1.DataSource = rstData;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }

    protected void cmdSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadGrid(txtSearch.Text);
    }
}
```

So, I am STRONG suggesting that you DUMP the sqldata source on the web page markup. Such Sqldata soruces on the page can be great for one time load or data display. But the VERY instant you want control, filters, and need to use code?

Quite much the SAME instant it is time to drop and toss out and remove the data source from the web markup. You be glad you did, and as you can see, you now have 100% EASY AND SIMPLE control of the data you shove into the GV,  and that includes endless possible use of simple code and buttons to add filters etc. to that data.

Comment: I appreciate your response, the error message now is gone after I remove the data sourced id but the searching button after I click on it nothing display I don't really know what the problems I follow your steps

Comment: Then edit your question - show the page markup, and then include your code behind. We can only guess without you showing the code you have so far.

Comment: before I followed your steps there was an error message but now it's gone and the searching box didn't display the data, yes sir I will do that.